# JMeter (pararell run threads)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I need to run my script. example: [image]

Here 10 threads, which running it alternately. He is creating create open connection, open connection, open conncetion... and also seven times, after read,read,read...7x samplers write,write, write..7x after read, read, read..x7.

I need to make open connection, read, write, read ten times parallel. How i can to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Once started each JMeter thread (virtual user) starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) as fast as it can.

If you want all 10 users to first execute Open Connection, then all 10 users to execute read, etc. you need to add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to be equal to the number of threads in your Thread Group.

This way each Sampler in the Synchronizing Timer's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) will be executed by 10 users at exactly the same moment so you will have

- 10 concurrent executions of open connection
- followed by 10 concurrent executions of read
- etc.

Comment: i dont need  10 users to first execute Open Connection, then all 10 users to execute read.
I need to make 10 user execute Open Connection, read, write pararell.

Comment: You cannot read without opening a connection first, these 3 requests need to be sequential.